# Prevent users from opening multiple instance of same website

Tags: php, javascript, html, session

I need help with PHP and JS scripting on web.

What I'm trying to do is something like a shopping cart. The product info is passed through the url paramaters and stored into SESSIONS in PHP. (Eg. http://www.mysite.com/pid=13)

If the user opens a new tab in browser and loads http://www.mysite.com/pid=25, the second tab will show the updated cart with 2 items, but the first tab will only show 1 item unless I manually refresh it.

What I need is:

1. When the user visits my site on the first time, information will be loaded.
2. When the user opens another instance of the same site (same url) on the browser (eg new tab), the second instance will be closed and the first instance will be refreshed to load some updated information.

In simple terms, I do not want the user to open multiple instance of my site in the same browser by force closing the second tab and refreshing the first tab. Is there any way I can do this using a combination of PHP and JS?

Comment: Sounds rather frustrating for the end user.

Comment: Big sites like Amazon don't bother with this, so if I were you I wouldn't either.

Comment: You should have more faith in your visitors if someone adds 2 items to the basket do you think there get confused, would you prefer your user right clicks to open in new tab and something odd happens then they click back or close and you lose the sale...

Comment: When you're trying to simply compare a few products, JS links that can't be opened in another tab are frustrating. There, closing a tab is angering the clients of your website ... The shopping cart needs to be exact at checkout moment, otherwise you know you're on the same site when you've opened 2+ tabs and that it won't be any cheaper to buy 3 products from 3 tabs. No need to update in realtime. It's normal, relax.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is not to change the refresh / loading behavior of your site. Instead of that i would change the way you are storing / saving items in your shop currently. I would suggest to do ajax postbacks if a customer puts an article into the shopping cart.

If you do it that way, you dont need to redirect the customer to any new site. The logic will "magically happen" as a backprocess.

If a customer visits his shopping cart later, you can load it from your database using the userid.

If you dont want to use a big library such as jquery for this approach, you can also replace your save logic with a simple popup wich does the job: => click add to cart button, open mypopup.php?articleId=5, save data into database, close popup automatically

Any questions? Dont hestitate to use the comments :)

Answer (score 0):

From your question I believe you add item(s) to cart via 'get'.
I would suggest you add via 'POST'
instead put your unique id and other item related data in a hidden form.
eg:

```
<form action="add_to_cart.php" method="post">
<p>Some Item Name</p>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Some Item Name" />
<p>Description: SOME DESCRIPTION</p>
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="Some Description" />
<p>Price: $123.00</p>
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="123.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="123" />
<!-- GENERATE TOKENS FOR YOUR FORM TO PREVENT XSS / CSRF attack -->
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="somerandomtoken" />
<input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" value="Add to Cart" />
</form>
```

In this case User can only add item to cart by submitting this form.
Hope this helps.